# Connecting to a Mac OS Classic computer over ethernet

Tags: ssh, login, remote, mac-os-classic

I'd like to be able to remote connect in (like SSH) to a Mac Classic laptop to retrieve some files. It's been forever since I've used Classic and I've forgotten everything. Is there a remote login setting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup ftp on either machine (probably on the OS X machine) and use an ftp client to upload. There have been no real changes to the ftp protocol in that time period.

Answer (score 1):

Classic Mac OS had built-in file sharing (AFP), but it never had a shell or command-line environment of any kind. The best way to retrieve files would probably to set up TCP/IP, enable file sharing over TCP/IP, double-check the owner user's name and password (reset if necessary), and hope that the AFP client on your Snow Leopard machine is backwards-compatible with such an old version of AFP. Don't bother trying to browse for it, just note what IP address it got and connect by IP address.